# Android: AlarmManager running every 24h - is it save to start only once?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i couldnt find an answer to this question.
I have a task to perform every 24h and i could either start the Pending Intent everytime i start the app, or i could start it once by testing with a boolean.

Its probably not good, performance wise, to unnecessarily start the Pending Intent so often, but starting it only once seems so fragile to me. I heard that Samsung phones shut down Alarm Intents after 3 days of not using the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a task to be done often, and for the long term, I would suggest moving away from `AlarmManager`.

`AlarmManager` will not work if the device is rebooted, I would suggest looking into `JobScheduler` which handles this case, or if you want to support backwards compat, you should look into Firebase's `Dispatcher` which will handle this for you.

I'm unsure what kind of task you actually want to do every 24 hours, but you should be fine passing Intents.

I personally use Firebase's `Dispatcher` for my app to sync to the server every 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Firebase Dispatcher looks interesting. Can you tell me if i can run it no matter if the app is running or not
and IF the app is running, it can refresh the UI

Comment: It will run if the app is dead or alive. And you can refresh the UI if it's alive. I use `EventBus` to just fire off an `Event`, and if the app is alive, it'll catch it and update the UI.